# How to create a list using spring with Java8?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, yaml

I´m trying to create a list from a yml and use it in other classes

The YAML structure

```
enviroment: enviroment1
    enviroment1:
    server1:
       url: UrlServer1

    server2:
       url: urlServer2

   server3:
       url: urlServer3

    server4:
       url: urlServer4

    letters:
      x: 123
      y: 456

   bar:
      aaa: 250
      bbb: 345          

   animal:
     pets:
         - key1: Meow
         - description1: dog        
         - key2: Woof
         - description2: cat

   enviroment2
   Same structure with other animals
   enviroment3
   Same structure with other animals
```

Then I create a class to extract the content of YAML(animals) according to Spring.

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "animal.pets")
public class Foo{

    private List<String> animals = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }

    public void setAnimals(List<String> animals) {
        this.animals = animals;
    }



}
```

I call the foo class in another class with the @Autowired notation, but when I print the list, it's empty

```java
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class Admin implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;
        //Code

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
          System.out.println(foo.getAnimals.toString());
          //Code
         }
}
```

Comment: It is empty because the YAML below `animal.pets` does not have a name `animals` define, not nothing fits the `setAnimals()` method.

Comment: Please describe what you expect the `animals` list to contain? Did you expect it to contain 4 strings, like `[ "key1: Meow", "description1: dog", "key2: Woof", "description2: cat" ]`? That doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

Comment: you have the wrong format in `yml` what is your expected output ? please take a look at this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: @Andreas Yes I expect that output, but you say that i don't have animals below animal.pets, I suppose that my YML has to be                                                                    animals :                                                                                                                                 
      pets:                                                                                                                                       
         animals:cat